# Penetration testing with PHP and Linux

Tags: php, security, debian, penetration-testing

For research purposes I've recently modified Debian sources for the `Linux Apache2 PHP5` stack and now I'd like to do some security penetration testing.

In particoular I modified the **PHP5** core overriding system `libc6` calls, the `SuEXEC` Apache wrapper and `clamdscan` daemon.

I'm trying some exploits, such as C99 madShell, ircBots, Mempodipper etc. But I think that are tools just for newbies (in fact I'm not really a security expert).

Can someone suggest me on how to do effective and evil pentests?

Comment: So you mean: Gimme the real cool stuff for free?

Comment: No, that's related to my question on ServerFault (http://serverfault.com/questions/386335/mod-vhost-alias-suexec-auto-selecting-uid-gid). I'd like to release my patches, but before I've to test it. But if that's an off-topic, it doesn't matter... Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably more of a question for https://security.stackexchange.com/ and they've loads comments/answers on pen testing.

To be honest, the answer to your question could go on forever but here are a few documents and links on effective pen-testing.

Presuming you want to do legitimate pentests and have permission to do the pentest (very important to get written sign-off, I can't emphasis that enough) then check out these documents from SANS -

http://www.sans.org/reading_room/analysts_program/PenetrationTesting_June06.pdf
http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/auditing/conducting-penetration-test-organization_67

A lot of pen testers have a bad name because many of them simply run Nessus and give a canned report (don't do that) so a bunch of top folk in the industry are trying to create a pen-testing standard so check this out - http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page.

If you want to learn how to write exploits and start messing with shellcode then check out the http://www.exploit-db.com/ site and maybe join the Metasploit mailing lists or IRC channels.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the penetration test to be meaningful and uncover more problems than just the low-hanging fruits, you really should hire a professional pentester or get somebody else with the necessary hands-on experience and practice to do it for you. A beginner's (no offence meant) textbook penetration test will not be meaningful to assess your systems' security. Also, since you are testing a security system or device you designed yourself, it makes a lot of sense to not do the testing yourself but throw someone against the problem who will also question the system's underlying assumptions for real-world practicability.